# Is there any way to copy contents (text) of a pop up window from a web page,automatically in an Excel cell?

Tags: javascript

There is a web page with products(description and prices).If someone wants more details has to click on a row in order to open a pop up window with more details about the certain product.Is there any way to automatically copy the contents of the pop up window into a cell next to the cells i get the data from my web query? the pop up window is like(....http://www.apage.com/product_info.asp?node_serial=&node_id=&ITEMID=0011262)
thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much that javascript (your tag) can access both the browser and Excel without user intervention, that would thoroughly break security.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the url is, I'm *fairly sure* in Excel you can do:

> File > Open > FileType=HTML > {paste URL}

If you don't have the URL, right click the popup, choose properties, then highlight the URL (it is selectable)

Windows will fetch the file for you and dump the HTML into a new spreadsheet.

Note, you will get all the junk that the page contains too, not just the data.  If you want an elaborate system, you're likely going to need a screen scraping application or use something like PHP's curl to pull data out of a URL.